# Javascript div not displaying

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a div that i created using `document.createElement("div")`. I then append a button to this div, and append this div to the an existing div in the dom. Any elements i append to the javascript created div using `.appendChild(Node)` do not display.
  i have no idea why, but here's the code. I am sure i am just missing something simple.

```
function login(){

    //get the login container div
    var login_container = document.getElementById("login_container");
    remove_all_children(login_container);

    //create the logout box
    var logout_box = document.createElement("div");
    logout_box.id = "logout_box";

    //create the logout button
    var logout_btn = document.createElement("button");
    var logout_btn_txt = document.createTextNode("Logout");

    logout_btn.id = "logout_btn";
    logout_btn.appendChild(logout_btn_txt);

    //add the logout button to the logout box
    logout_box.appendChild(logout_btn);

    //add the logout box to the login container
    login_container.appendChild(logout_box);

    //alert(login_container.firstChild.id);
    //shows "logout_box"

    //alert(login_container.firstChild.firsChild.id);
    //shows "logout_btn"

    //login_container.appendChild(logout_btn);
    //the logout button displays if i do this

}

function remove_all_children(parent){

    if(parent.hasChildNodes()){

        while(parent.childNodes.length >= 1){

            parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? If there's a typo, say, in "login_container", you'll get an exception and most of the code won't run. If you're sure it runs, can you see the elements in the DOM? Lastly, are you sure login_container is visible?

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/HH3a5/  Can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah, typos were the first thing i checked for. It runs and i can see the elements in the dom. the login_box div is duplicated for some reason.

ive copied my code into jsfiddle and it runs fine. The dom is exactly as i would expect it to be. I am unable to replicate the problem, but will keep trying.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but i am using chrome on ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: resolved the duplicate login_container issue. Had an error in my php. I can see the login_box element in the dom, but i still can't get it to display. My code runs perfectly in jsfiddle. I can't seem to replicate the problem. Im stumped. thanks guys.